# How to balance magic item that utilizes gems?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, homebrew, pricing

I have a really cool idea for a magic item but I am trying to figure out how to balance it. The premise of it is that it is a hilt that changes form when a gem is inserted in the pommel. The type of weapon and type of damage it does depends on what type of gem is inserted, the rarer the gem the more bonus damage it does. ( Garnet would probably be a handaxe or something similar with +1d4 fire damage with an emerald being a dagger with +4d4 poison and a diamond being any weapon +4d8 force) I think this is a really cool concept but I am trying to figure out how much these gems should cost to keep it balanced. For reference, I am using this([How big is a gemstone in the DMG gemstone table?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133835/how-big-is-a-gemstone-in-the-dmg-gemstone-table)) for size stuff.

Comment: Understanding how to ask a good question about how to go about homebrewing is rather difficult — especially as you seem to ask for how to homebrew and a homebrew review of your concept at the same time, I suggest you read highly rated [tag:homebrew] questions and https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question to figure out how to focus and on what to focus this question. We will need a detailed and clear question.

Comment: You clearly plan on this being modular, but in what way do you plan on expanding the player's inventory? 4d8 force damage is clearly very strong and also much stronger than 1d4 fire damage. Are the gems for one character or for any character?

Comment: How difficult/time-consuming is it to change a gem? Does the pommel require attunement? ... do the gems? How valuable does the gem need to be (and, does the value of the gem affect anything - eg., does a 10,000 gp diamond work better than a 100 gp diamond)? Does using a gem in this way affect the gem at all?

Comment: @goodguy5 I'm trying to figure out what a minimum price/size would be for the gems, obviously diamonds are much more expensive then a garnet when they are the same size so a diamond will be more effective then a garnet

Comment: @minnmass It takes an object interaction to take out/put in a gem and you need to be attuned for it to actually change forms. I'm trying to find a good minimum price for it to work, but likely yes if you had more expensive gems it would do more damage but with diminishing returns

Comment: I would caution balancing on cost, because the players only get as much money as the DM allows, and only find the gems the DM allows too. Balance the item first (hint: it isn't - at all!), worry about the upgrade mechanism afterwards.

Comment: Don't forget, you can always hop into [chat] to workshop and quickly discuss things that don't work well in our q&a format.

Comment: Please edit your question with the specifics you have in mind so we can actually answer. I have a proposition to calculate based on existing references, but would like to avoid answering in comment.
Even if you don't like my proposed method, you could have some inspiration without having to worry too much about the gem sizes.
(A usually 10gp Tiger Eye might need to be an actual full sized orb to worth enough for specific effects if you want to emphasize on all gems being able to be inserted.)